# Batch / How to open a .txt file with default editor?

Tags: batch-file

Let's say I had a batch file:

```
echo Would you like to open text.txt? (y/n)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto OPENFILE
if %cho%==y goto OPENFILE
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM
:OPENFILE

:END
```

How would I open the text file in batch?

Comment: Either `"text.txt"`,  `Start "" "text.txt"` or `Start "" /Wait "text.txt"`, should do it, depending upon your specific needs.

Comment: With some looking up, I think `Start` would open the text file like a program, and I could use that to open something like Notepad that a lot of people have on their computers, but they might prefer an editor like VSCode

Comment: `Start`, as well as just using the `filename.ext`, should open the file using whichever program is registered as the default for `.ext` files. If you wanted to stipulate the program, you'd use e.g. `Start "" "P:\ath\to\your.exe" "filename.ext"`. Please try all three examples, and those in this comment to see that I'm correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for both answering my question and showing me `Choice`! You're a great helper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three examples based upon my earlier comment:

```bat
Choice /M "Would you like to open text.txt"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :END
"text.txt"
:END
```

```bat
Choice /M "Would you like to open text.txt"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :END
Start "" "text.txt"
:END
```

```bat
Choice /M "Would you like to open text.txt"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :END
Start "" /Wait "text.txt"
:END
```

*You'll note that I've used the more suitable `Choice` command instead of `Set /P`, which gives little control ove what the end user inputs.*

Comment: Off topic but- thanks for the tip on `Choice`! Seems like a better way for user input/choosing.